# Why I lose bibliography numbering when I switch to IEEE - Alphabetic Order style in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, ordering, bibliography

When I use IEEE - Reference Order style for my Bibligraphy table I get the references numbers OK. Well formated as [2].

But when I switch to Alphabetic Order style I lose the numbers, and in their places always is [BO]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this style does not come with Word, you probably downloaded it somewhere. Didn't it come with instructions at the download site?

Comment: Thanks, it was here http://bibword.codeplex.com/releases/view/19764 and here http://bibword.codeplex.com/releases/view/24823

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found a solution. Once you extract the various styles provided by Bibword into your corresponding styles folder, you will also need to note the asterisk after the new style that you select. I needed to use the IEEE-Alphabetical style for my paper, and it had an asterisk alongside it.
Style names ending on a * indicate that the BibWord Extender tool is needed to use their complete functionality.
You will need to download this tool:
https://bibword.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BibWord%20Extender

Then, run the tool, point it to the same style folder where you extracted your  styles folder and a small box pops up. Select the style from that small box, then browse to the document name that you are working on. Then click extend which is on the far left of the box.

This fixed the [BO] citation issue perfectly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the FAQ on that first link seems pretty straightforward:

Q: Why do I get 'BO' between brackets instead of a number when using the IEEE - Alphabetical style*?

A: The IEEE - Alphabetical* style requires the [BibWord Extender](http://bibword.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BibWord%20Extender) tool to function properly. This tool will decide the on the numbers to place instead of 'BO'.